# Use [ngValue] and [selected] in select tag

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to set the default value of a select tag containing objects in a form, using [selected] and [ngValue]. But for some reason they seem incompaptible.

Example code:

```
<select id="selectedStore" *ngIf="showStore" 
    class="form-control" 
    formControlName="homeStore" 
    tabindex="{{getTabIndex('homeStore')}}">

    <option *ngFor="let store of availableStores"
        [ngValue]="store" 
        [selected]="store.storeId == personalInfo.homeStore?.storeId">
        {{store.name}}
    </option>

</select>
```

This code ends up just showing blank as the default value. If I remove the [ngValue] it works fine, except that then it's the store.name value that gets selected, instead of the store object.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15):

You can use `compareWith` with `[ngValue]`

eg:

```
<select id="selectedStore" *ngIf="showStore" 
    class="form-control" 
    formControlName="homeStore" 
    tabindex="{{getTabIndex('homeStore')}}" [compareWith]="compareByID">
        <option *ngFor="let store of availableStores"
            [ngValue]="store">
            {{store.name}}
        </option>
</select>

compareByID(itemOne, itemTwo) {
    return itemOne && itemTwo && itemOne.ID == itemTwo.ID;
}
```

See: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13349

Example Compare select options: http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2017/03/24/what-is-new-angular-4/

**Note: this support is added in Angular4**

Answer (score 9):

`[ngValue]="..."` is supposed to be used with `[(ngModel)]`. `[selected]` doesn't work with `[ngValue]`.

Comment: So, any suggestions how to solve this problem in reactive forms?

Comment: In reactive form you assign the value to the control instance. `[selected]` is not related to reactive forms.

Comment: How do you set selected value in reactive forms? API please? tx Sean

Comment: this.myForm.get('mycontrol').setValueAndValidity(newValue)`

Comment: For god sake , where is the documentation of `ngValue` ? angular.io doesn't has a documentation for it.

Comment: I don't know, I just saw the discussion about the feature request and the pull request that implemented it.

Comment: I found angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor

Answer (score 7):

Update your select tag as below, **ngModel** will hold selected value

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem.Page.ID" class="form-control" (change)="OnPageSelected($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let page of PageCollection.Items;" value={{page.ID}}>
        {{page.Name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for reactive forms

Answer (score 1):

Im posting my asnwer because maybe someone is getting the same behavior.

Im receiving a value from API and I need to assign to the form control then you can not assign it directly. You need to use the same `availableStores` instance array and find the value inside. 
Thats the way to get `[ngValue]` works perfectly.

```
control.setValue(this.availableStores.find(
  store => store.name === this.valueFromAPI.name
));

<select      
  class="form-control"
  formControlName="homeStore"      
  >
  <option
    *ngFor="let store of availableStores"
    [ngValue]="store">
    {{store.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Reference https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor check the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Add a

```
[ngModel]="yourDefaultObject"
```

to your select and same for the first option

Comment: This doesn't work for reactive forms

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, using Reactive Forms, with a select that has [ngValue] set up in the options, if you wanted to programmatically set the currently-selected option using Typescript from the associated Component, you can do it in this manner:

```
this.myReactiveForm.controls["mySelectControlName"].setValue( desiredValue );
```